# Unable to install Postgres extension pg_prometheus and prometheus-postgresql-adapter manually on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, postgresql

I am trying to setup Prometheus with PostgreSQL DB on a CentOS server. I am able to install Prometheus and PostgreSQL on the server but unable to **install pg_prometheus extension** and the **prometheus-postgresql-adapter**.

Need help to manually install pg_prometheus extension and prometheus-postgresql-adapter on CentOS?

I am aware that there are Docker images from TimescaleDB for this but I am trying to avoid using Docker for my proof-of-concept, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

### Install PostgreSQL on CentOS

Download the PostgreSQL Global Development Group RPM for CentOS x86-64

`wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch.rpm`

Run the PGDG RPM package

`sudo yum install pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch.rpm`

Install and Setup PostgreSQL Server and all its components

`sudo yum install postgresql10-server.x86_64 postgresql10-contrib.x86_64 postgresql10-devel.x86_64 postgresql10.x86_64`

`sudo /usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-setup initdb`

`sudo systemctl start postgresql-10`

`sudo systemctl enable postgresql-10`

### Secure your Postgres Environment on CentOS

`sudo passwd postgres` (Enter a New Password)

`su - postgres`

`psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '<Your-New-Password>';"`

Change `listen_addresses` to `listen_addresses = '*'` in /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/postgresql.conf

Change `local   all             all   peer` to `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust` in /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf

Restart the PostgreSQL Service with `systemctl restart postgresql-10.service`

### Check CentOS Firewall Rules to allow remote connection to PostgreSQL DB

`sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5432/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8088/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8089/tcp --permanent`

`sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

### Install Prometheus

Download Prometheus fof Linux amd-64

`wget https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v2.6.0/prometheus-2.6.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

`tar xvzf prometheus-2.6.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

`cd prometheus-2.6.0.linux-amd64`

Update config for Prometheus

`vi prometheus.yml` (job_name: 'prometheus', target: [':8088'])

Run Prometheus

`nohup ./prometheus --config.file="prometheus.yml" --web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:8088" &`

### Install pg_prometheus PostgreSQL Extension

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-10/bin`

`git clone https://github.com/timescale/pg_prometheus.git`

`cd pg_prometheus`

`make`

`make install`

### Prometheus Storage Adapter

Download the pre-built binary for Linux amd-64

`wget https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter/releases/download/0.4.1/prometheus-postgresql-adapter-0.4.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

`tar xvzf prometheus-postgresql-adapter-0.4.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

Run the Prometheus Storage Adapter

`./prometheus-postgresql-adapter -pg.host "<Your-IP-Address>" -pg.port "5432" -pg.user "postgres" -pg.password "1Password2" -pg.database "<Your-DB-Name>" -pg.schema "dbo" -pg.table "<Your-Table-Name>" -web.listen-address "172.16.152.29:8089" -log.level "debug" -pg.prometheus-log-samples -pg.read-only`